# Selenium Firefox driver Capabilities with PHP

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, phpunit, remotewebdriver

I am including the path of remote webdriver to invoke browser and other capabilities.
Now I need to set firefox profile capabilities such as an e.g for downloading the file I need to directly save it rather than opening the file.
I have tried doing these but it throws me this error.

```
"Fatal Error Class Facebook/Webdriver/FirefoxProfile not found in C:xampp/htdocs/zoho_ws/github/index.php  on line 14"
```

I know I am missing something header files but I still don't know how to include it. I am using [Facebook Webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) to write selenium testcases.
I need to set browser capabilities but when I try doing these code it gives me error.
*

```
<?php
// An example of using php-webdriver.
namespace Facebook\WebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
//use Facebook\WebDriver\Firefox\FirefoxProfile;
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
// start Firefox with 5 second timeout
/*//ORIGINAL CODE
$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'; // this is the default
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::firefox();
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 5000);*/
//ORIGINAL CODE ENDS HERE
$profile = new FirefoxProfile();
$profile->setPreference(
  'browser.startup.homepage',
  'https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/'
);
$caps = DesiredCapabilities::firefox();
$caps->setCapability(FirefoxDriver::PROFILE, $profile);
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($url, $caps);
// navigate to 'http://docs.seleniumhq.org/'
//$driver->get('https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=aRELWZKeOrDy8Aep3LyIBw');
// adding cookie
$driver->manage()->deleteAllCookies();
$driver->manage()->addCookie([
    'name' => 'cookie_name',
    'value' => 'cookie_value',
]);
$cookies = $driver->manage()->getCookies();
//print_r($cookies);
// click the link 'About'
//input[@name='q']
/*$input = $driver->findElement(
    WebDriverBy::name('q')
);
$input->sendKeys('php')->submit();*/
//button[contains(.,'Export All')]
$driver->get('https://my.ecwid.com/cp/');
```

Can Anyone help me out to set firefox capbilities?

*

Comment: where is your Firefox driver? keep that in the same path from where you are calling the php code

Comment: Didn't get u can you pls explain me in bit detail?

Comment: do you have the firefox driver? means the geckodriver for firefox? you need to download it and keep it in the folder of the php file or you need to register it in the environment variable. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver